# What does it mean to say that MongoDB is atomic on its level of write operations?

Tags: mongodb, atomic

I'm reading MongoDB's [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/) but not seeing an actual definition of what they mean by "atomic".  Can somebody help explain this, please?

Answer (score 3):

It refers to multiple clients simultaneously updating the same record.
When two clients write to the same document, they will not mix the content, only one of them will update the document, so you will not have some fields from one client and other fields from another client.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  Thanks a lot!